# about the commandline mode of disk2vhd

Tags: backup

How to write parameter t, then i can use its volume shadow function?

[picture 001](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rAlQe.png)

Look this note, "-c" is to no use of the volume shadow copy.But,how to use?there is no words about it.I guess,don't write "-c",means to use this function?

But,no matter how to use these parameters,the following popup program window,that small “use volume shadow copy" box,is always not chosen...
[picture002](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pgl7f.png)

So,please tell me,how to write the parameters,then I can use the "volume shadow copy" function to create the backup file?

Comment: You should post the full text from the image into the question.  Have you gone to sysinternals.com or tried to contact the author Mark Russinovich? You might find him on linkedin at https://www.linkedin.com/in/markrussinovich/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contact the author of the program. His name is in the popup dialog that you show as picture002. Also please post text of what is on the pictures in the messages so people can see what you're asking without clicking links.